# Xamarin Android live stream of microphone to crtmpserver

Tags: xamarin, streaming, webrtc, audio-recording, rtmp

I have an app to be done that requires a tablet to stream audio to a server in realtime. This is because there will be another client apps also on android (and probably iOS but for now I'm interested on Android) that will be fetching for the live audio stream.

After some search, I found [crtmpserver](http://www.rtmpd.com/) that supports live streaming and that also says that it can stream

> To and from embedded devices: Android, IP cameras, Hardware encoders

I have already been able to setup it on my localhost and test with a .mp3 via `rtmp` to check if it was working.

Now my question is what do I need to do on iOS to stream the audio from microphone to the server? 
Do I need `ffmpeg` for Android? 
Is `WebRTC` a possible solution for this?

It is the first time that I do something like this. Btw, I'm using Xamarin for this project and I'm also open to solutions that require making binds to native code of Android.